# Sql Server Reporting Services: how to calculate percentage difference?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a report in SQL Server reporting services, grouped by a column "ProdType".
Each row is a Year. How to calculate Subtotals but with the Difference of value instead the Sum ?

At the moment the expression is : =Sum(Fields!Tot.Value).
Is there a Difference function ?

Thank you

EDIT: In particular, i've only 2 records per group:

```
Prodtype         Year         Value
A                2000         10
A                2001         12
  Diff.                       +20%

B                2000         5
B                2001         10
  Diff.                       +100%
```

My main problem is to create the "Diff." row with the percentage increment / decrement!

Comment: What would the difference function return if you gave it three values, say 1, 10, & 20?

Comment: Is the first member the only positive of the algebric sum? 
The opposite of Sum(value) should be Sum(-value), but I think it does't apply here; I think you must distinct one positive to start from.

Comment: Please show an example data and results set.  Also, keep in mind that subtraction (like division) isn't _communative_ - that is (as @AndreaColleoni has already partially pointed out), the _order of operations_ **matters**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reporting services also includes the [First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms159861%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) and [Last](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms155794%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) aggregate functions, which will work provided you do always only have 2 values in each group. You should be able to perform a % calculation using those values.